# gatsby-background-image crop left side of background image on browser resize

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I can create the result that I want using regular css on a div using the code below. The image is stuck to the right side of the screen and the left side of the image crops so that when you shrink the size of the screen you still see the castle in the image.

```css
#bgImg{
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfepb.jpg");
  height: 225px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: right center;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div id='bgImg'><div>
```

I'm unable to create the same result using `gatsby-background-image`. The image always crops the right side of the image.

I tried creating a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-https-kyzk3?file=/src/components/header.js), but unfortunately the image isn't appearing and I can't find out why

---

This is the code that I have which crops the right side of the image instead of the left

```js
const bgImgProps: FluidObject = data.bessImg.childImageSharp.fluid
const otherImgProps: FluidObject = data.logoImg.childImageSharp.fluid

<BackgroundImage
        Tag="section"
        role="img"
        className='w-100 h-100'
        style={{
          backgroundPosition: "right center",
          objectFit: "fill"
        }}
        fluid={bessImgProps}
        backgroundColor={`#040e18`}
      >
         <div className='header-outer-container d-flex justify-content-center'> 
            <a className='only-gt-md' style={{height: "130px", width: "350px"}} href="/">
              <Img 
                className='w-100 h-100'
                fluid={logoImgProps}
                fadeIn={false}
                loading="eager"
                imgStyle={{objectFit: 'contain' }}
              ></Img>
            </a>
        </div>
      </BackgroundImage>
```

```css
.header-outer-container{
    height: 225px;
}

header{
    min-height: 225px;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

This is what it looks like, but I want the image to crop from the other side, so that the castle remains visible, like in the plain css example above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give the class `.headerBG` to my background image and create css that looks like

```
.headerBG::before{
    background-position: right center;
}
```

I then didn't need any of the other lines which stated `background-position: right center;` resulting in JS and CSS which looked like

```js
const bgImgProps: FluidObject = data.bessImg.childImageSharp.fluid
const otherImgProps: FluidObject = data.logoImg.childImageSharp.fluid

<BackgroundImage
        Tag="section"
        role="img"
        className='w-100 h-100'
        style={{
          objectFit: "fill"
        }}
        fluid={bessImgProps}
        backgroundColor={`#040e18`}
      >
         <div className='header-outer-container d-flex justify-content-center'> 
            <a className='only-gt-md' style={{height: "130px", width: "350px"}} href="/">
              <Img 
                className='w-100 h-100'
                fluid={logoImgProps}
                fadeIn={false}
                loading="eager"
                imgStyle={{objectFit: 'contain' }}
              ></Img>
            </a>
        </div>
      </BackgroundImage>
```

```css
.header-outer-container{
    height: 225px;
}

header{
    min-height: 225px;
}

.headerBG::before{
    background-position: right center;
}
```